Is there a proof of the de Moivre-Laplace central limit theorem along these lines?
Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ denote independent identically distributed random variable with, say, distribution given by $P(X_i= \pm 1)=1/2$. As usual, set $$S_n=X_1+ \cdots +X_n.$$
It follows from Skorokhod's representation theorem and the central limit theorem that there exists a sequence $T_n$ of random variables such that $S_n$ and $T_n$ have the same distribution and $T_n / \sqrt{ n}$ converges almost surely to a random variable $N$ with the standard normal distribution. It is clear that $S_n$ themselves do not do this job.
Now, constructing such a sequence $T_n$ without appealing to Skorokhod's representation theorem and the Central limit theorem would give a proof of the CLT in this special case.
My question is: is there any known proof of the CLT that goes along these lines?

This is probably cheating, but I will comment anyways. For real-valued random variables $X, X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ with CDFs $F_X, F_{X_n}$ and $X_n \to X$ in distribution, a Skorokhod representation on $((0, 1), \mathfrak{B}(0, 1), \mathrm{d}x)$ is given by $\tilde{X}n(u) := \inf{c \in \mathbb{R} ,\vert, F{X_n}(c) \geq u}$. To show that these random variables converge pointwise is the same as showing that $F_{X_n}$ converges pointwise to $F_X$ and exactly that is proved in at least one of the common proofs of the de Moivre-Laplace CLT.

So maybe the goal should be to construct $T_n$ in a more "probabilistic" way.

@unwissen: yes, I consider this cheating, as it really does not give you a proof of CLT if you don't already believe in it. I am thinking mostly of a probabilistic construction where perhaps the value of $T_{n+1}$ is obtained by tweaking the value of $T_n$ in a mild way to guarantee convergence.
